# UnitTesing with Autofac, Moq - Getting Value cannot be null exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, autofac

I'm using EF6. The generated code is something like:

```
public partial class MyDataContext : DbContext,IMyDataContext 
{
    public MyDataContext() : base("name=mydata")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<getProjectsDraft> getProjectsDrafts { get; set; }
}
```

and the dbcontext Interface is like below

```
public interface IxmcmcDbContext: IDisposable
{
   DbSet<getProjectsDraft> getProjectsDrafts { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the Autofac for the DI and the registration is done at my global.asax.cs as below

```
//Entity Registering
builder.RegisterType<MyDataContext>().As<IMyDataContext>();
```

All my DI is working fine but when I implemented unit testing using xUnity I am getting below error

Basetest Code:

```
public class BaseTest
    {
        public static Mock<DbSet<T>> CreateDbSetMock<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements) where T : class
        {
            var elementsAsQueryable = elements.AsQueryable();
            var dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
            dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.Provider);
            dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.Expression);
            dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.ElementType);
            dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(elementsAsQueryable.GetEnumerator());
            return dbSetMock;
        }
    }
```

and Project Test

```
public class Projects_Test : BaseTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void GetDraftProjectsList()
        {
            // Arrange
            var fixture = new Fixture();
            var draftProjects = new List<getProjectsDraft>
             {
                fixture.Create<getProjectsDraft>()
             };
            var draftMock = CreateDbSetMock(draftProjects);
            var myDataContextMock= new Mock<IMyDataContext>();
            myDataContextMock.Setup(x => x.getProjectsDrafts).Returns(draftMock.Object);
            var projectService = new ProjectRepo(mediciContextMock.Object);

            // Act
            var draftproject = projectService.GetDraftProjects(true, "test-02", "Test");

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(draftproject);
        }
    }
```

However, I get the `"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"` error on the //Act draftproject.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `myDataContextMock.SetupGet(x => x.getProjectsDrafts).Returns(draftMock.Object);`

Comment: can you please share the stack trace / inner exception of this exception. Also, where are you registering your mocked db context to the interface in the test project?

Comment: @TylerHundley.. it's not working... Thanks for reply

Comment: @Saravanan... Added 
where are you registering your mocked db context to the interface in the test project? ==> i think i am not registering it

Comment: I am following this 
https://www.jankowskimichal.pl/en/2016/01/mocking-dbcontext-and-dbset-with-moq/

Comment: Do you have to mock your dbcontext? If you are not, you can use inmemory provider efcore?

Comment: yes i need mock my dbcontext

Comment: @EmreHIZLI and I am using ef6 .net framework not core

Comment: Can you share `getProjectsDraft` class? Just to get a picture of how `fixture.Create<getProjectsDraft>()` fill it at the end... Is `ProjectID` string? Can it be null?

Comment: Share the class, ProjectID is an Int and fixture is filling it with some random number every time .. I am able to see it

Comment: And if you try to mock `AsNoTracking` as well? I think that is the problem since that method returns `null`, like: `draftMock.Setup(x => x.AsNoTracking()).Returns(draftMock.Object)`

Comment: Yes, You are correct. I removed the AsNoTracking from my linq query and it's working fine .. so what is my solution for this.. let me search

Comment: @Satti Can you just mock it as I proposed in the comment ^^^?

Comment: @Johnny.. thanks it's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, the `DbSet` is mocked properly but looking at the method, you will notice the `AsNoTracking` method which is actually not mocked and it returns `null`.

```
lstDraftProj = (from proj in mydbEntities.getProjectsDrafts.AsNoTracking()
                orderby proj.ProjectID descending
                select proj).ToList();
```

That is also suggested by stack trace:

> System.ArgumentNullException   HResult=0x80004003   Message=**Value**
> **cannot be null**. Parameter name: **source**

Since you are already mocking `DbSet` try mocking the `AsNoTracking` method as well, e.g:

```
draftMock.Setup(x => x.AsNoTracking()).Returns(draftMock.Object)
```